# Transform ndarray shape

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I'm using python / Numpy to store small images into ndarray.
I'm stuck when I'm trying to transform an ndarray from 32,32,1 shape to 1,32,32,1. Any help ? Thanks

Comment: Hey, are you satisfied with one of the answers?

Answer (score 0):

You need to expand the dimensions of the numpy array. Use [`np.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html).

```
arr = np.expand_dims(arr, axis=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

`arr[np.newaxis, :, :, :]` will work

Answer (score 0):

Instead of explicitly adding an axis you could also explicitly reshape it to add the axis:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.ones((32, 32, 1))  # just ones for demonstration purposes

>>> reshaped = arr.reshape(1, *arr.shape)
>>> reshaped.shape
(1, 32, 32, 1)
```